# Session timeout issues when upload to web

Tags: php, session, timeout, session-cookies

**My code is working perfectly on localhost. However, when i upload web, its shows session end time as when the browser session ends no matter what is the option selected. here is the code for first page**

```
<pre><code>
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_SESSION['over18'])){
header("location: index.php");
}

if(isset($_SESSION['under18'])){
header("location: leave.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$remember = $_POST['remember'];

$birthday = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day, $year);
$difference = time()-$birthday;
$age = floor($difference/31556926);

if($age >= 18){
    $_SESSION['over18']=1;
    switch ($remember) {
        case 1:
            header("location: index.php?sessionid=1");
            break;
        case 2:
            header("location: index.php?sessionid=2");
            break;
        case 3:
            header("location: index.php?sessionid=3");
            break;
        case 4:
            header("location: index.php?sessionid=4");
            break;
        case 5:
            header("location: index.php?sessionid=5");
            break;
        case 6:
            header("location: index.php?sessionid=6");
            break;
        default:
            header("location: index.php?sessionid=1");
            break;
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['under18']=0;
    header("location: leave.php");
}
}<!-- language: lang-none -->
p class="pos_fixed3">Remember me for: select name="remember">
option value="1">This Session Only</option>
    option value="2">1 Hour</option>
    option value="3">5 Hours</option>
    option value="4">1 Day</option>
    option value="5">1 Week</option>
    option value="6">1 Month</option> </p>
</select>

</pre></code>
```

**And my code for index.php is below**

```
if(isset($_GET["sessionid"])){

$session = $_GET["sessionid"];
 } else {
$session = "";
}
switch ($session) {
        case '1':
            session_set_cookie_params();
            break;
        case '2':
            session_set_cookie_params('3600');
            break;
        case '3':
            session_set_cookie_params('18000');
            break;
        case '4':
            session_set_cookie_params('86400');
            break;
        case '5':
            session_set_cookie_params('604800');
            break;
        case '6':
            session_set_cookie_params('18144000');
            break;
        default:
            session_set_cookie_params('');
            break;
    }

session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['over18']){
header("location: age.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IN index.php .
start session start of pgae

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['over18']){
header("location: age.php");
}
```

After this your code.

```
if(isset($_GET["sessionid"])){

$session = $_GET["sessionid"];
 } else {
$session = "";
}
switch ($session) {
        case '1':
            session_set_cookie_params();
            break;
        case '2':
            session_set_cookie_params('3600');
            break;
        case '3':
            session_set_cookie_params('18000');
            break;
        case '4':
            session_set_cookie_params('86400');
            break;
        case '5':
            session_set_cookie_params('604800');
            break;
        case '6':
            session_set_cookie_params('18144000');
            break;
        default:
            session_set_cookie_params('');
            break;
    }
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you for answer but did not make any difference.. still dont know why its working localhost but not on web..

Comment: please check that session is start in the starting of page in every page

Comment: yea it surely does coz i use same header.php in every page with require_once("header.php"); and the code is actually on header.php not index.php

Comment: funny thing is everything looks okay and reads all values which i can see with echo. no error or anything. so annoying